# How to get type to appear over of an image?

Tags: css

Here is my site: http://www.matthewtbrown.com/newsite/index.html

I want to rollover and the type to be over of the the image and 10px from the top and the left. I don't want to the type to appear until I rollover.

I'm referring to the type that I want over each thumbnail of my portfolio. For instance, in the top left image of my portfolio, I want the type to read "Avid Interplay Production Brochure" and to be over the image.

Here is some of my css:

```
.item {
   background: #136073;
   border-style:solid;
   border-color:#fff;
   border-width:1px;
} 

.item img:hover { 
   opacity: 0.3; 
}
.item .text {
   top:10px;
   left:10px;
}
.item .text:hover {
   opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: This is really unclear : What is "type"? What exactly are you trying to do? Oh, and try to name your CSS classes in a way that you kind of know what they are / do when you read their names, easier for everybody, especially you.

Comment: @xaccrocheur - I provided more details to my question. I've also been able to come up with a solution, which is setting .item to relative and setting .text to absolute. I'm currently under a question ban, so if you could upvote me, I'd appreciate it. I don't mean to post bad questions, but I'm not a web developer by background and am still in the early learning stages. And yes, I should be properly naming my classes. I know what it means, but no one else does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to show the descendant `.text` element when hovering over an `.item` element (which presumably includes a descendant `img` element). If that's the case then you just want to put the `:hover` pseudo-selector on the `.item` selector, not the descendant selectors:

```
.item {
   background: #136073;
   border-style:solid;
   border-color:#fff;
   border-width:1px;
} 

.item:hover img { 
   opacity: 0.3; 
}
.item .text {
   position:absolute; /*Notice this was added to correctly position the element*/
   top:10px;
   left:10px;
}
.item:hover .text {
   opacity: 1;
}
```

**ALSO**

To set opacity in a cross-browser fashion, you'll need some IE specific properties set:

```
opacity : 0;
zoom    : 1;
filter  : "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
filter  : alpha(opacity=0);
```

**BONUS**

You can animate the opacity change in modern browsers by setting a `transition` property for the `img` and `.text` elements:

```
.item img,
.item .text {
    -webkit-transition : opacity 500ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition    : opacity 500ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition     : opacity 500ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition      : opacity 500ms ease-in-out;
    transition         : opacity 500ms ease-in-out;
}
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/LJnEH/1/

Comment: note that IE's filter styles don't work like that; if you specify two `filter` styles, the second one will take precedence, and the first will not be used (just like any other CSS property). If you need both effects, you need to combine the two of them into a single `filter` statement. It's ugly, but that's how it works, and yes, it's almost impossible to get right if you want the two styles to come from separate selectors. One way to get around it is to have nested elements, and apply one filter to each element.

Comment: @Spudley The two filters are for different versions of IE. The second one is preferred so it comes last, overwriting the first in versions of IE where both are read. Since they do the same thing (they are not different effects), this will not have any negative effects on the opacity change to an element. I settled on this order of property settings because it is the most cross-browser compliant (i.e. more versions of IE respect the opacity change using this order). Here is some good reading on the subject: http://css-tricks.com/css-transparency-settings-for-all-broswers/

Comment: @MattBrown Looking at your website, it looks like you just need to set the opacity for the `.text` elements so they don't start at `opacity:1` (i.e. you won't see the change from `opacity:1` to `opacity:1`...).

Comment: The text is appearing outside the div.

Comment: The type I'm referring to is "Avid Interplay Brochure". www.matthewtbrown.com/newsite

Comment: @MattBrown If you want the `.text` element to appear over the image, you have to specify a `position` property, I used `position:absolute` in my example since that is what it looks like you're attempting to do. Without setting a specific `position` property, the element is set as `static` and cannot be moved with `left`/`right` properties. If that doesn't solve your issue then you need to be more specific as you haven't really described your problem thus far.

Comment: @Jasper - uh, yes of course they are. I feel a bit silly now. Having said that, the `"prodID:...` syntax generally wants it to be `-ms-filter`. I think that's what caught me out; I don't normally see two `filter` styles without one of them having `-ms-` on it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it was an issue where I needed one element, the .item, to be be relative, but the .text to be absolute.